# Flex item does not grow properly in Safari

Tags: css, flexbox

In Chrome, when set `flex: 1` on a flex child, when it's content becomes larger than the flex child, the flex child grows.

However, that does not happen in Safari.
In Safari, it behaves like putting `table-layout: fixed` on a `table`.
How do we unfix it in Safari?

```css
padre {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
child {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
child:last-child {
  background: yellow;
}
under-child {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<padre>
  <child>
  </child>
  <child>
    <under-child></under-child>
  </child>
</padre>
```

[The same in JsBin](https://jsbin.com/bitaku/12/edit?html,css,output)

[image]

*Please note that any of the fixed sizes in the example are just for illustrational purpose. In reality, as I'm building fluid layouts, I don't have access to any fixed sizes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `width: 150px;` from `under-child`, or set `overflow: hidden;` on `child`.

So the container is 200px, and each child would be 100px due to `flex: 1;`, the extra 50px causes the overflow, and somehow Safari couldn't adjust it.

If you need the last child div to be 150px wide, you can set `flex: 0 0 150px;` on `child:last-child`.

```css
padre {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
child {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
child:last-child {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
under-child {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  /* width: 150px; */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<padre>
  <child></child>
  <child>
    <under-child></under-child>
  </child>
</padre>
```

As an alternative solution, you can probably achieve the layout with CSS table. it works well without setting any fixed width on the `child` element.

```css
padre {
  display: table;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
child {
  background: green;
  display: table-cell;
}
child:last-child {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50%; /*this will be auto adjusted*/
}
under-child {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<padre>
  <child></child>
  <child>
    <under-child></under-child>
  </child>
</padre>
```

**Edit:**

I can confirm that your original example works just fine in latest [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) (same results as in Firefox and Chrome), so it is very likely a bug, and has been fixed already in a future stable release.